# How to download 'Million Song Dataset ' to my local disk?

Tags: download, bigdata

The data is http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/

Is there any direct way use like 'wget' to get it?

Or how to get it from amazon ec2 virtual machine?